# Массив в языке C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Привет а как можно разделить весь массив(то есть разделить все его числа вместе) на любое число, это вообще возможно или нет, а также хотел бы узнать как присвоить весь массив(то есть все его числа вместе) любой переменной, извините если вопрос слишком легкий я просто не понимаю как это сделать, заранее спасибо за ответ ;)

Comment: Через цикл, по-другому никак.

Comment: "как присвоить весь массив(то есть все его числа вместе) любой переменной" — непонятно, что вы хотите. Допустим, что это можно — что должно быть в переменной при присваивании массива, скажем, {1,2,3}?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке  С++ есть шаблон класса `std::valarray`, представляющий  массив и оптимизирован для численных расчетов и имеющий многочисленно полезных функции_членов. Не нужно игнорировать этот класс для реализации матриц и при не тривиальных численных расчетов(в особенности, если размер массива не подлежит изменению, хотя, если очень нужно, то его размер тоже возможно изменить). В вашем случаи тоже он будет удобен. Не важно как реализованы функции_члены и не  члены для этого класса. Важно, что вы можете написать просто (не беспокоясь об эффективности):

```
void task(std::valarray<int>& array, const int n)
{
    array = n + array[0];
    //всем членам будет присвоен правый операнд
    array /= n;
    //все члены разделить на n
    //и много другое...
}
```